# Invoking Get-ChildItem command on Network Path in C# code not working

Tags: c#, powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to invoke the `Get-childitem` from the C# code on network drive to retreive xml file but it is not working. The code does not return files nor throws exception.

```
    string FileSelectionCommand = "Get-ChildItem " + "\\Btapp-prod\\e$\\BizTalkMessages\\Proudction\\" + "*.xml -rec | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge " + "\"" + searchdate + "\"" + "}";
        shell.Commands.AddScript(FileSelectionCommand);
        // Execute the script  
        var fileresults = shell.Invoke();
```

Comment: Have you tried without `Where-Object`? Might be that the `searchdate` string is not well formed/suited for date comparison

Comment: UNC paths start with 2 backslashes. Looks like you're missing a leading backslash (and the other one to escape it): `"\\\\Btapp-prod\\e$\\BizTalkMessages\\Proudction\\"`

Comment: The command string works fine if I am pointing to a local folder, It is the network folder it does not return any files or throw errors.

Comment: @samjack as you've written it, you _are_ referring to a local folder, because you've left out a backslash.

Comment: The following change does not work either. Could you tell me where did I leave the backslash."Get-ChildItem " + @"\\Btapp-prod\e$\BizTalkMessages\Production" + "*.xml -rec | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge " + "\"" + "10/2/2014" + "\"" + "}";